# How to log the @Test method details in testreport using testNG

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have a class and It contains one @Test method(sampleTest1). In that method I have 4 @Test method calls from some other class. When I'm running my test cases through TestNG It logs only the main test method in output console and said that 1 test method passed.

How to log all the 4 test methods which defined in sub-class file?

Please can someone help me out.

Thanks,
Sasi

Comment: Why cant you define them in parent class?

Comment: I have a flow like test switch. Which is in parent class and control my execution activity. Please assume that the sampleTest1 is my switch method based on if condition It has to invoke an appropriate test methods which is in child class file.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot have parent child relationship between the test cases for TestNG, if you try to call them from parent test they will execute but they wont be part of the report and you may not have any clue if they fail.

> Annotation Transformers Approach

If you want to run a method based on some condition then you might have to look at [Annotation Transformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers)

You need to create a class by implementing the `IAnnotationTransformer` interface. Check for your condition in transform method set the Enable property to true or false to disable the `@Test testcase`.

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  private MyParentClass parent;
  public MyTransformer(MyParentClass parent){
      this.parent = parent;
  }
  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)
  {
    if (checkConditionForMethod(testMethod.getName())) {
      annotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
  public boolean checkConditionForMethod(String methodName){
       return parent.isValidSwitchForMethod(methodName);
  }
}
```

You add the Annotation Transformer programmatically:

```
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setAnnotationTransformer(new MyTransformer(parentClassInstance));
```

> Inner classes approach

Other way for nested test cases is creating inner class for your parent class and then define the test cases within the inner class **but without any condition**.

For example if you below class structure:

```
TestClassParent [Testcase1Parent] [Testcase2Parent]
  |_ TestSubClass1 [Testcase1Sub1] [Testcase1Sub1]
  |_ TestSubClass2 [Testcase1Sub2] [Testcase2Sub2]
```

Then the order of execution would like this: and you need to define your test cases according to the order to execution to achieve your goal.

```
Testcase1Sub1
Testcase2Sub1
Testcase1Sub2
Testcase2Sub2
Testcase1Parent
Testcase2Parent
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Testng logs only the @Test method it calls himself. But if you are calling by creating objects of the testclass. it it wont log that as a separate test.

So what you can do is you can let testng call them and maintain the flow of execution by using dependsongroups and dependsonmethods. But beware once you use depends on groups testng will not preserve your test class order anymore.